# changing style background color to a user selected rgb value

Tags: javascript, php

I focus mostly on PHP. I have a cookie "themeColor"
am trying to make it so a user can select a color and change the background color of 3 divs at will. Currently, I am able to do this with the #menu style

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['themeColor'])) {
        $color = urldecode($_COOKIE['themeColor']);

    echo '<script>document.getElementById("menu").style.background="rgb(' . $color . ')"; </script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("main").style.background="rgb(' . $color . ')"; </script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("footer").style.background="rgb(' . $color . ')"; </script>';

    }
```

the other 2 divs will not change color. I assume it is a syntax error but I have been looking at this for hours now and would appreciate some help

[image: showing that the first js command is executing but the other 2 do not follow]

Ask for any data
edit// adding html markup for menu main and footer

"BEGIN FILE header.php" - starting at #menu -

```
<div id="menu">
            <h1>Solor Hive</h1>

    </div>
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE['themeColor'])) {
        $color = urldecode($_COOKIE['themeColor']);
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("menu").style.background="rgb(' . $color . ')"; </script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("main").style.background="rgb(' . $color . ')"; </script>';       
    }
    if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    setcookie('theme', "", time() - 3600);
    setcookie('user', "", time() - 3600);
    header("Refresh:0; url=./index.php");
}




?>
    <div class="main" id="main">
        <div id="content">
```

"END OF FILE header.php"

"BEGINNING FILE footer.php"

```
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">

<?          if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
    echo '<div class="profile">';
    echo '<a href="./index.php">My Profile</a>';
    echo '<a href="./people.php">User Search</a>';
    echo '<a href="./chat-room.php">Chat</a>';
    echo '<a href="./ppix.php">My Pictures</a>';
    echo '<a href="./games.php">Games</a>';
    echo '<a href="./tools.php">Tools</a>';
    echo '<a href="./help.php">Help</a></div>';
    echo '<form method="POST" id="logout" action="#">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout"/>';

    }

    ?>


        <h4>Made by <a href="http://www.solorside.wordpress.com">Solorside</a></h4>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

"colorpicker.php"

```
<? include("./header.php"); 


if (isset($_POST['color'])) {

$rgb = $_POST['color'];

setcookie('themeColor', $rgb, time() + (86400 / 12), "/");

}


?>



<canvas width="512" height="512" id="canvas_picker"></canvas>

<form method="POST" id="colorpicker" Action="#">

<div id="rgb">RGB: <input type="text" name="color" id="color"></input>
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Theme Color">

</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_picker').getContext('2d');



var img = new Image();

img.src = './data/image.png';

$(img).load(function(){

canvas.drawImage(img,0,0);

});


$('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){

var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;




var imgData = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

var R = imgData[0];

var G = imgData[1];
var B = imgData[2];



var rgb = R + ', ' + G + ', ' + B;
  $('#rgb input').val(rgb);

});



</script>

<? include("./footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: post your html markup

Comment: Could you please share menu, main and footer ?

Comment: If you have the color stored on a cookie it makes no sense to use JS to change the color, why just don't print the cookie value on the desired `div` as `style` ? Your way is overthinking.

Comment: @Troyer Thanks! totally fixed my problem lol

Comment: @Solorside I'm happy it helped you ! I write down a solution to make it cleaner without style, using `CSS` classes, we are PHP coders and sometimes is hard to think easy solutions :)

Comment: LOL the latest site im working on does something similar to this but thanks to this topic I was able to write a js/php/sql visual editor in like 4 hours xD thanks again for your help @Troyer

Answer (score 0):

Move your Javascript/ JQuery just above `</body>` tag.

Comment: I mean you have to add the js below all your html code - just above </body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would try without JS, because for me makes no sense to search on the DOM when I have the value stored already on a `COOKIE`, I would apply on the top of the body the next code:

```
<style>
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['themeColor'])) { ?>
        .bg-color {
           background-color: <?php echo urldecode($_COOKIE['user']); ?>; /* COOKIE */
        }

<?php } else { ?>
        .bg-color {
           background-color: #767577; /* default one */
        }
<?php }  ?>
</style>
```

So, I will apply the `bg-color` class on the desired `div` I want to change with the cookie, then when the cookie is set it will apply the background color.